# Click on a tags with hrefs don't redirect me

Tags: jquery, href

So right now I have a small script in JQuery that allows me to have a collapsing menu. My problem is that when I have this script on my page and click on one of the elements in the subheader, I'm not redirected to the new page (i.e. if I'm on my about page currently and I click on Contact Info, I'm sent back to the top of the page instead). I'm not sure how my script affects a tags and hrefs.

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".subheader").hide();
    $(".expand").click(function () {
        if ($(this).text() == "+") {
            $(this).text("-");
        } else {
            $(this).text("+");
        }
        $(this).parent().next(".subheader").slideToggle(500);
    });
});
```

HTML:

```
<div>
    <h3 class="heading"><a href="/about">About</a> <span class="expand">+</span></h3>
    <ul class="subheader">
        <li><a href="/about">about 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="/about">about 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="/about">about 3</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div>
    <h3 class="heading"><a id="contact" href="contact">Contact Info</a> <span class="expand">+</span></h3>
    <ul class="subheader">
        <li><a href="contact">contact 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="contact">contact 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="contact">contact 3</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: code looks ok, does console return any error?

Comment: The posted code is not the issue, should work just fine.

Comment: shouldn't it be: href="/contact"> ?

Comment: @roasted - it doesn't have to be, in this case it'd be a relative URL vs an absolute URL. Looks like he probably has code somewhere else on the page that is hijacking his links, or maybe he's got href="#contact" by mistake.

Comment: @Shaddow I have unrelated errors in the console having to do with other parts of the page. I might look into that in a bit.

Comment: @Justin - [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/C6RHn/) its working ...

Comment: @MikeP I do not have any hrefs that refer to some id. All of them have a similar syntax where it is just href="some-endpoint". I'll look t o see if I have some other code on my page that may be hijacking my links.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out why none of my href's were redirecting me. It was all because of this one line.
After removing it, all my href's were working again. So if anyone ever bumps into this problem in the future, make sure you check which scripts you have within your HTML file and watch out for duplicate lines because they may (or may not) break your links. It worked for my instance at least.

```
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I dont even.... This could not possibly be your problem. Removing that line just broke all your JQuery utilizing Javascript. There must have been other code that was changing your HTML in a way that broke the links.

Comment: @thatidiotguy Well I tried everything. I've been checking all my Javascript files. I even had them commented out the lines that linked to them but I missed this one line. After getting rid of this, my links worked once again. I had two lines pointing to JQuery actually. So I guess I better way to word things is to watch out for duplicate lines.